# VB.NET creating a class to make chosen picturebox movable with mouse

Tags: vb.net, mouse

I'm working on a project using VB.NET (VS2015). I'm going to be making a lot of movable icons and therefore, I need to make the process of making them faster!

I would like to create a class which I can use to make picture boxes movable with the mouse.

Ex. `Make_Movable(picturebox1, label1)`

The "label1" is the label under it. I already have a code for that. I'm just making in invisible and making it visible again. (Tested and worked).

NOTE: I only need the picturebox to move! I already have a code for the label, but for that I need to be able to move the picturebox.

Is that possible?

The only thing I tried and can come up with is this:

```
Dim capt = 0
Dim a
Dim b

Public Sub IMMove(lbl, pb)
    If capt = 1 Then
        lbl.Visible = False
        pb.Location = New Point(pb.Location.X + (Cursor.Position.X - a), pb.Location.Y + (Cursor.Position.Y - b))
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub IMDown(lbl, pb)
    a = Cursor.Position.X
    b = Cursor.Position.Y
    capt = 1
End Sub

Public Sub IMUp(lbl, pb)
    pb.Location = New Point(pb.Location.X + (Cursor.Position.X - a), pb.Location.Y + (Cursor.Position.Y - b))
    capt = 0

    lbl.Visible = True
    lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X, lbl.Location.X - (lbl.Width + lbl.Width / 2) + lbl.Width + lbl.Width / 3)
    lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.Y, pb.Location.Y + pb.Height)
End Sub
```

But that won't work, the picturebox just dissapears and I have to do something for each event. Ex. in picturebox1.MouseDown: `IMDown(Me, picturebox1, label1)`

Help please :)

Comment: There is already such a beast on CodeProject

Comment: From your code, you are doing nothing to the object. You want to take advantage of the MouseMove, MouseDown and MouseUp events for the control. :)

Check this article which will explain in detail how you can do what you want to accomplish to a label (easily modified into a picturebox):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14770/Create-your-Own-Runtime-Movable-Windows-Forms-Cont

Comment: Seems like what I've been looking for! Thank you.

Comment: I didn't work :/ It's for VS2005/VS2008

Comment: The code should still be compatible.

Comment: @Joe that was the first project i "copied" in my working career. i'm feeling nostalgic... BTW, the code is usable even now. i downloaded the code and opened it with VS2015 community edition. it just work

Comment: @PaddiM8 Please tell us what you're having trouble with so we can further troubleshoot. As stated above by another user, the code still works.

Comment: Yeah, that might work but I can't get it to my project!'